# Spring AOP or AspectJ way for selecting parents of a given class

Tags: aspectj, spring-aop

I have a pointcut definition in Spring AOP, which selects a certain set of classes, let say A. Is there a possibility to select the parent classes of all classes in A? I would prefer a solution in Spring AOP, but I would be also thankful for a predicate definition in AspectJ that would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily select A and all sub classes for A with `A+` , but as class A might have many root classes (parent for parent for parent .... Object) I think you can't create selector for this case. But you can create general pointcup and check inside aspect's advice call,  if it's one of parent class for A . BUT it will reduce performance a bit as you add aspect's call / check. I don't know your requirements , but if it's acceptable try this.